# No tengo un error de sintaxis, pero al momento de correr el programa algunas operaciones me dan y otras no

Tags: c

Tengo un par de problemas, hice un código que me permitirá hacer conversiones, todo el menú me lo han asignado a hacer con switch, no tengo error alguno de sintaxis, el programa corre, pero al momento no se por que algunas conversiones me dan y otras no o simplemente se me confunden de operación a realizar. Adjunto el código a continuación, estuve pensando en usar `#define` para definir la constantes de por ejemplo Torr o Atmósfera Física y eso.

También quería saber si podría hacer que una vez seleccionado el menú, pudiera hacer que se borrara para que solo se mire el menú seccionado.

**Operaciones que no cumplen su propósito:**

**1-** Fahrenheit a Celsius y este es el error=> Por favor ingrese los grados Fahrenheit ==> 0.000000

El resultado es: -0.00º Celsius

**2-** El conversor de unidades de presión, ninguno me muestra resultado.

**3-** El conversor de unidades de energía, todos se me direcciona hacia el de Vatios-Hora y no realiza la operación.

Estos son los problemas que tengo al ejecutar el código.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int op,op2,op3,op4;
    double Celsius,Fahrenheit,Kelvin,operacion,operacion2,operacion3;
    double Pascal,Lin,AtmosferaFisica;
    double Joule,Vatioh,KiloC,KiloJ;

    printf ("\n ****--------------------------------------------****\n");
    printf ("\n        Este es un conversor de unidades. \n");
    printf ("\n ****--------------------------------------------****\n");
    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el tipo de Convertidor.\n");
    printf ("\n 1- Unidades de Temperatura.");
    printf ("\n 2- Unidades de presi%cn",162);
    printf ("\n 3- Unidades de energ%ca",161);
    printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
    scanf ("%d",&op);
    switch (op)                                                                                 //Menu principal.
    {
        case 1:
            printf ("\n Unidades de Temperatura.\n");
            printf ("\n ***--------------------------***\n");
            printf ("\n Por favor seleccione una opci%cn.\n",162);
            printf ("\n 1- De Celsius a Fahrenheit");
            printf ("\n 2- De Celsius a Kelvin");
            printf ("\n 3- De Fahrenheit a Celsius");
            printf ("\n 4- De Fahrenheit a Kelvin");
            printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
            scanf("%d",&op2);
            switch (op2)                                                                        //Menu Conversor.
            {
                case 1:                                                                         // Unidades de Temperatura.
                    printf ("\n De celsius a Fahrenheit");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Celsius ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Celsius);
                    operacion=(Celsius*9/5)+32;
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %.2f%c Fahrenheit",operacion,167);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf ("\n De Celsius a Kelvin");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Celsius ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Kelvin);
                    operacion=(Celsius+273.15);
                    printf("\n El resultado es: %.2f%c Kelvin",operacion,167);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf ("\n De Fahrenheit a Celsius");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Fahrenheit ==> ");
                    printf ("%f",&Fahrenheit);
                    operacion=(Fahrenheit-32)*(2/9);
                    printf ("El resultado es: %.2f%c Celsius",operacion,167);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf ("\n De Fahrenheit a Kelvin");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Celsius ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Fahrenheit);
                    operacion=Fahrenheit-32*5/9+273.15;
                    printf ("\n El resutado es: %.2f%c Kelvin",operacion,167);
                    break;
                default: 
                    printf ("ERROR Escriba una opcion valida.");        
            }   
        case 2:                                                                                 //Unidade de Presion.
            printf ("\n Unidade de Presi%cn",162);
            printf ("\n ***---------------------------***\n");
            printf ("\n Por favor seleccione una opci%cn",162);
            printf ("\n 5- De Pascal a Libra por pulgada cuadrada.");
            printf ("\n 6- De Pascal a Torr");
            printf ("\n 7- De Pascal a Atm%csfera F%csica",162,161);
            printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
            scanf ("%d", &op3);
            switch (op3)
            {
                case 5:
                    printf ("\n De Pascal a Libra por pulgada cuadrada.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Pascal ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Pascal);
                    operacion2=Pascal/1895;
                    printf("\n El resultado es: %f lbf%cin%c",operacion2,47,253);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf ("\n De Pascal a Torr");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Pascacl ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Pascal);
                    operacion2=(Pascal/133);
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %f Torr",operacion2);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf ("\n De Pascal a Atm%csfera F%csica",162,161);
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Pascal ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Pascal);
                    operacion2=Pascal/101325;
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %f atm",operacion2);
                    break;
                default: 
                    printf ("ERROR Opcion Invalida");
            }
        case 3:                                                                                 //Menu de Energia.
            printf ("\n Unidades de Energ%ca",161);
            printf ("\n ***------------------------------***\n");
            printf ("\n Por favor seleccione una opci%cn",162);
            printf ("\n 8- De Joule a Vatio-Hora.");
            printf ("\n 9- De Joule a KiloCaloria.");
            printf ("\n 10- De Joule a kiloJoule.");
            printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
            scanf ("%d",&op4);
            switch (op4);
            {
                case 8:
                    printf ("\n De Joule a Vatio-Hora.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Joule ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Joule);
                    operacion3=Joule/3600;
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %f Wh",operacion3);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    printf ("\n De Joule a Kilocaloria.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Joule ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Joule);
                    operacion3=Joule/4184;
                    printf("\n El resultado es: %f Kcal",operacion3);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    printf ("\n De Joule a KiloJoule.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Joule ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Joule);
                    operacion3=(Joule/1000);
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %f KJ",operacion3);
                    break;
                default: 
                    printf ("ERROR Seleccione una opcion valida");  
            }   
    }
    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sigo sin entender cuales son las operaciones que dan error. Eso es lo que deberías de agregar en la pregunta..

Comment: Ya he agregado los inconvenientes.

Comment: Quieres borrar el texto anterior que se muestra en la pantalla? Si es así, puedes usar esta función: `system("cls")`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estaba revisando el código y logre encontrar algunos problemas por el cual no lograba funcionar tu programa:
1. el primer problema se debe a que es escrito la función printf, cunado debería de ser scanf, por lo que marca un pequeño error y no deja guardar el numero que queremos introducir.
2. la única forma de que logre solucionar este resultado es pasar algunas de tus variables en tipos float, de esta forma si funcionan todos de manera correcta.
3. aquí hay un pequeño problema al momento de crear el switch, ya que después de asignar la variable que evaluara, escribes ";", por lo que el programa lo cierra casi de manera instantánea, te mando el codigo "corregido", saludos.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int op,op2,op3,op4;
    double Celsius,Fahrenheit,Kelvin,operacion;
    double Lin,AtmosferaFisica;
    double Vatioh,KiloC,KiloJ;
    float Pascal, operacion2,operacion3, Joule;

    printf ("\n ****--------------------------------------------****\n");
    printf ("\n        Este es un conversor de unidades. \n");
    printf ("\n ****--------------------------------------------****\n");
    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el tipo de Convertidor.\n");
    printf ("\n 1- Unidades de Temperatura.");
    printf ("\n 2- Unidades de presi%cn",162);
    printf ("\n 3- Unidades de energ%ca",161);
    printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
    scanf ("%d",&op);
    switch (op)                                                                                 //Menu principal.
    {
        case 1:
            printf ("\n Unidades de Temperatura.\n");
            printf ("\n ***--------------------------***\n");
            printf ("\n Por favor seleccione una opci%cn.\n",162);
            printf ("\n 1- De Celsius a Fahrenheit");
            printf ("\n 2- De Celsius a Kelvin");
            printf ("\n 3- De Fahrenheit a Celsius");
            printf ("\n 4- De Fahrenheit a Kelvin");
            printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
            scanf("%d",&op2);
            switch (op2)                                                                        //Menu Conversor.
            {
                case 1:                                                                         // Unidades de Temperatura.
                    printf ("\n De celsius a Fahrenheit");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Celsius ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Celsius);
                    operacion=(Celsius*9/5)+32;
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %.2f%c Fahrenheit",operacion,167);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf ("\n De Celsius a Kelvin");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Celsius ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Kelvin);
                    operacion=(Celsius+273.15);
                    printf("\n El resultado es: %.2f%c Kelvin",operacion,167);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf ("\n De Fahrenheit a Celsius");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Fahrenheit ==> ");
                    scanf ("%d",&Fahrenheit);
                    operacion=(Fahrenheit-32)*(2/9);
                    printf ("El resultado es: %.2f%c Celsius",operacion,167);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf ("\n De Fahrenheit a Kelvin");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese los grados Celsius ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Fahrenheit);
                    operacion=Fahrenheit-32*5/9+273.15;
                    printf ("\n El resutado es: %.2f%c Kelvin",operacion,167);
                    break;
                default: 
                    printf ("ERROR Escriba una opcion valida.");        
            }   
        case 2:                                                                                 //Unidade de Presion.
            printf ("\n Unidade de Presi%cn",162);
            printf ("\n ***---------------------------***\n");
            printf ("\n Por favor seleccione una opci%cn",162);
            printf ("\n 5- De Pascal a Libra por pulgada cuadrada.");
            printf ("\n 6- De Pascal a Torr");
            printf ("\n 7- De Pascal a Atm%csfera F%csica",162,161);
            printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
            scanf ("%d", &op3);
            switch (op3)
            {
                case 5:
                    printf ("\n De Pascal a Libra por pulgada cuadrada.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Pascal ==> ");
                    scanf("%f",&Pascal);
                    operacion2= Pascal/1895;
                    printf("\n El resultado es: %.5f lbf%cin%c",operacion2,47,253);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf ("\n De Pascal a Torr");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Pascacl ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Pascal);
                    operacion2=(Pascal/133);
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %.5f Torr",operacion2);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf ("\n De Pascal a Atm%csfera F%csica",162,161);
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Pascal ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Pascal);
                    operacion2=Pascal/101325;
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %.5f atm",operacion2);
                    break;
                default: 
                    printf ("ERROR Opcion Invalida");
            }
        case 3:                                                                                 //Menu de Energia.
            printf ("\n Unidades de Energ%ca",161);
            printf ("\n ***------------------------------***\n");
            printf ("\n Por favor seleccione una opci%cn",162);
            printf ("\n 8- De Joule a Vatio-Hora.");
            printf ("\n 9- De Joule a KiloCaloria.");
            printf ("\n 10- De Joule a kiloJoule.");
            printf ("\n Ingrese la opcion ==> ");
            scanf ("%i",&op4);
            switch (op4)
            {
                case 8:
                    printf ("\n De Joule a Vatio-Hora.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Joule ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Joule);
                    operacion3=Joule/3600;
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %.5f Wh",operacion3);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    printf ("\n De Joule a Kilocaloria.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Joule ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Joule);
                    operacion3=Joule/4184;
                    printf("\n El resultado es: %.5f Kcal",operacion3);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    printf ("\n De Joule a KiloJoule.");
                    printf ("\n Por favor ingrese el valor de Joule ==> ");
                    scanf ("%f",&Joule);
                    operacion3=(Joule/1000);
                    printf ("\n El resultado es: %.5f KJ",operacion3);
                    break;
                default: 
                    printf ("ERROR Seleccione una opcion valida");  
            }   
    }
    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```